# Functions and trig question, finding minimum value

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are shown below:
>
> $$f(x) = 3x^2 + 12x + 16,$$
> $$g(x) = 2 \sin(2x - \pi) + 4$$
>
> Using complete sentences, explain how to find the minimum value for each function and determine which function has the smallest minimum $y$-value.

How do I find the minimum value? Can anyone show me?

Comment: Hints: think derivative. Also, plot each.

Comment: Have you tried to resolve it? You need to derive the function, set it equal to zero to find maximum and minimum. To sort can use the second derivative.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it even without derivative.

**about f:** suppose $f(x)=3x^2+12x+16$ polynom from second degree (i.e in form of $ax^2+bx+c$). its minimum is located in $x_0=\frac{-b}{2a}$ and you can simply substitute.

**about g:** $\forall a\in\mathbb R,|\sin(a)|<1$, so in your function you're looking for an $x_1$ s.t $\sin(2x_1-\pi)=-1$.

Comment: Actually the $x_0$ at the minimum is $x_0=-b/2a$ and then *that* value of $x$ should be plugged in.

Comment: I fixed it. thanks.

Comment: Yes. Now it looks good, and can be done with that approach by an algebra/trig student before learning calculus. Such courses usually cover the range of sine, cosine and the vertex of a parabola. (+1 for the simple accessible method).